# Linux, how to know the current boot disk

Tags: linux, boot

I've a Linux Centos (5.0) machine with 2 disks. I was changing the SATA cable to one of the disk when I realized that depending on what SATA slot I'm using, the OS starts from sda or sdb.

The problem is that I have daily backups from sda to sdb (merely copies), if by accident someone change the SATA cable, I will screw up and overwrite new data with old data.

The only thing that I know is, that current boot disk is the good one. How I can certainly know which disk is the current boot disk (sda or sdb)?

Additional info: I've no physical access to the machine.

Comment: The solution would be to stop using "sda" and "sdb" and start using disk UUIDs...

Comment: grawity is absolutely right, once you solve this you should switch to using UUIDs instead, which prevents this sort of problem.

Comment: Like grawity said. Those names sda and sdb are dependent on the order they are found at boot time. Usually the lower numbered port is sda. So they will change if you swap the cables. sda will then be called sdb, and vice versa. So you can't go by that name to identify them. They need a unique name...

Comment: BTW, since you have two disks you might want to just make them RAID 1, and let the OS do the sync/copy operation for you. Then you won't have to deal with it.

Comment: About the RAID1, yes it would be the best option but I had too much troubles to set it and gave up.

Comment: About UUIDs, I will research a little about it, I didn't know it. But won't that be the same as create a directory in sda called "disk1" and another in sdb called "disk2"? When the machine boots, if I found the "disk2" in sda, I could presume that disks switched. Am I wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Linux: get the current boot disk's device name](https://superuser.com/questions/948276/linux-get-the-current-boot-disks-device-name)

Answer (score 2):

First, use disk UUIDs like @grawity said.

If you want to know the UUIDs of everything that looks like a block device to Linux, use the `blkid` command.  I think you can do something like `blkid /dev/sda` to find out the UUID of `sda` as well.

Another thing you can do is use the symlinks in `/dev/disk/by-id` which are created for each disk based on the bus it's connected to and its reported model and serial number.

---

Technically, Linux doesn't know or care about the device it was loaded from, because

- that's the bootloader's job - which runs before the kernel is running - to load the kernel into memory.
- anything that's not in the kernel needed at boot is in the initramfs (initrd), such as drivers, early userland utilities - loading this is also the bootloader's job.

Now, after Linux loads, boot scripts or whatever other mechanism running under the kernel tries to mount a root file system so you have other things to run besides the kernel, as well as swap, etc.  Basically all the stuff in your `/etc/fstab`.  This is what you really care about and that file will have the information you need.  You can use UUIDs in `/etc/fstab` (and I believe most distributions already use them) - so with a couple `grep`'s and `cut`'s you can get UUIDs out of here that you want.

Example (this probably can be done better): `cat /etc/fstab | grep "/ " | cut -f 1 -d " "`

And you can use the output of that for `blkid` to find the UUID of your root file system or whatever other partition.

Comment: Also, instead of/in addition to UUIDs you could also use labels. They're more human-readable, after all.

Answer (score 1):

For any one that needs the boot disk name I answered [here](https://superuser.com/a/1602235/1240921) but basically it is this:

```
lsblk -no pkname $(findmnt -n / | awk '{ print $2 }')
```

Comment: If one of your existing answers, answers this question, you should flag it as a duplicate.  Incomplete answers that just link to others answers are not really helpful.  Every answer must stand by itself.  Since there isn’t anything wrong with your other I have done exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

I too would suggest using UUID's, but short of that, if you are not using LVM or RAID or something else which obscures the underlying block device using "df" will expose which drive is mounted.   (Even if you are using LVM or RAID you will probably have a /boot partition which can tell you this).

Alternatively "hdparm -a /dev/sdX" will tell you the model AND SERIAL number of the drive, so you could run this command and grep to work out which hard drive is which.

Answer (score 0):

Ran into this myself, and found
 `mount | head -n 1 | cut -d " " -f 1`
returns the device node of whatever is mounted at `/` (assuming `/` is always first in the list)

Answer (score -1):

```
awk '$2 == "/"' /proc/self/mounts
```

Comment: ese comando me devuelve: rootfs / rootfs rw 0 0
/dev/root / ext3 rw,data=ordered 0 0. ...