# Linux: get the current boot disk's device name

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, usb

When booting a machine by USB stick,

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

outputs you two devices marked with an asterisk, and you'll never know which was the boot device.

I need a list of all disks attached to the current machine where

```
sed -ne 's/.*\([sh]d[a-zA-Z]\+$\)/\/dev\/\1/p' /proc/partitions
```

is a good way, it outputs

```
/dev/sda
/dev/sdb
```

That  does give me a clue which is the boot device, which is essential as a want to boot from the one and secure delete the other - automatically
(stick in, boot, let it run...) as I do that on a bunch of machines at one time, making sure that no data remains on customer computer hard disks.

```
awk '$2 == "/"' /proc/self/mounts
```

That gives you the UUID-number - but how to find the `/dev/sd?` belonging to it?

(Hint about "use UUID" isn't helpful - I don't want to reconfigure the system, I want to clean it. Of course I can assign new UUIDs when doing that, it costs a second, but that is definitely not the goal, and still misses the fact that I don't know which device `/dev/sd?` to give a new one.)

[`dban`](http://www.dban.org/) did the job, but won't be free to use in future.

Comment: `sudo blkid` will give you the UUID (and other info) for each `/dev/sd*` device. You can also look at `/dev/disk/by-uuid/` content where each UUID is a symlink to a specific `/dev/sd*`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You almost have it with your `awk` invocation. A few small tweaks should be enough.

```
awk '$1 ~ /^\/dev\// && $2 == "/" { print $1 }' /proc/self/mounts
```

The `$1 ~ /^\/dev\//` part requires that any satisfying line names a device somewhere under /dev. Now all we need is a mapping from the device UUID name to the kernel-assigned name, which is easy since all names listed will either be that name directly, or a symbolic link (ultimately) pointing to that name, so we can just feel them to `ls -l` like so:

```
ls -l $(awk '$1 ~ /^\/dev\// && $2 == "/" { print $1 }' /proc/self/mounts)
```

This should give you a single line of output which tells you which physical device the root file system is currently mounted from. **It won't be foolproof, so I wouldn't automate anything potentially destructive based on this alone,** but for a human who just wants some help in figuring out which device to point at, it should be enough.

Comment: That gives me

    lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 10 Jul 29 20:39 /dev/disk/by-uuid/330a4fd2-db87-4641-941d-a29e79540241 -> ../../sda6

which is good enough, as it contains the "sda", which leeds to the conclusion "I may delete sdb". (Remember, the intentions is that the system is booted by USB stick and all other disk shall be shredded).

Answer (score 3):

You should find where your `/` is mounted.

```
findmnt -n / | awk '{ print $2 }'
```

Lets say the result you get is `/dev/sda1`. Use that to find parent device:

```
lsblk -no pkname /dev/sda1
```

And that should give you lets say `sda`. You can prepend that with `/dev/` if need be.

Dunno how fool proof this is. But it might be better than [this](https://superuser.com/a/948453/1240921) answer.